# a further strain of the virus

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, american-english, british-english, transatlantic-differences

Is it okay to speak of "a further strain of the virus" in a context about the Delta variant of COVID-19?

Does "a further variant of the virus" sound more natural?

I'm wondering if there's a BrE/AmE difference.

Comment: There is probably a technical difference between a "strain" and a "variant".  I suggest you ask this question at [biology.se]

Comment: The question is about the combinability of "strain" and "further." It's a linguistic question, not a biological one.

Comment: Both are OK to me (Canadian). If you're uninterested in the technical difference between "strain" and "variant", then both are natural ways to talk about Delta.

Comment: In AmE there is no usage of the term “further” in this context. We would use “another”.